# Which sets do these pieces belong to? Orange (non-Lego) and orange/black (Lego)

Tags: set-identification, clone-brands

Which sets do these pieces belong to?

Thanks!

[image]

[image]

Comment: Bottom left looks like the bagged micro set of the Guardians of the Galaxy ship

Answer (score 8):

The first isn't (entirely) Lego - you can see the open studs on the top-left build.

The second seems to be 70645 [Cole - Dragon Master](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=70645-1) [image: 70645]

Comment: Thank you for your response.  How about the other pieces in the first picture?  They may not be all from the same set.

Answer (score 8):

The other LEGO sets seen in first picture have pieces of [Arctic Ice Crawler (60192)](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=60192-1)

[image]

And [Drone Explorer (31071)](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=31071-1)

[image]

Comment: Top-right are from the ice-crawler, bottom-right is drone explorer. Top-left appears to be partial non-Lego (studs look really wrong on several pieces). Bottom left appears to be Lego, but is not from either set as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 5):

Bottom left is from [The Guardians' Ship (30525)](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=30525-1), you can tell from the cockpit.

[image: Lego model of the Guardians of the Galaxy's ship from Infinity War. Significantly smaller than minifigure scale.]

I believe that makes the top left the only clone brand sub-assembly.